# Android Navigation Drawer BaseActivity sample

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Can someone suggest me a tutorial how to create a BaseActivity for the Android Navigation Drawer ?

Or can anyone post a sample BaseActivity for the Navigation Drawer including the layout ?

Comment: check the link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. download the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download sample Code from Google n i have edited that code as basic navigation drawer with fragment no imageview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

     //   mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
      //  mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
       // mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
       // mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
   /*     // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
       // mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
      //  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                   host Activity 
                mDrawerLayout,          DrawerLayout object 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,   nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret 
                R.string.drawer_open,   "open drawer" description for accessibility 
                R.string.drawer_close   "close drawer" description for accessibility 
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    //@Override
   /* public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }*/

    ///@Override
 /*   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)==true) 
            {
                 mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            }else 
            {
                 mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);

            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }*/

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Select the Position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
       // fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    //@Override
  /*  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }*/

  //  @Override
  /*  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }*/

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
       // public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_fragment, container, false);
           // int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            //String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

           // int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                      //      "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
          //  ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
          ///  getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the help of fragments. Go through following which have sample code and video tutorial.
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html